# Evaluate index before printing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE that evenly distributes `\n` dots around a circle of some `\radius`:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{RoyalAzure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def \n {4}
            \def \radius {3}
            \draw[dashed] circle(\radius);
            \filldraw[color = RoyalAzure] 
                  foreach \s in{1,...,\n}{
                     [color =  black] (-360/\n*\s:-\radius)circle(1.7pt)
                      node[anchor=-360/\n*(\s)]{$g^{\s}$}
                  }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following image:

[image: constellation]

How can I relabel the nodes such that $g^0$ starts from the positive $x$-axis (i.e. at 0 angle) and iterates with increasing angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clockwise rotation:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{RoyalAzure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{4}
  \def\radius{3}
  \draw[dashed] circle[radius=\radius];
  \filldraw[color=RoyalAzure]
    foreach \s in {0,...,\numexpr\n-1\relax} {
      (-360/\n*\s:\radius) circle[radius=1.7pt]
      node[color=black, anchor=360/\n*\s] {$g^{\s}$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Anti-clockwise rotation (only one minus sign to remove):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{RoyalAzure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{4}
  \def\radius{3}
  \draw[dashed] circle[radius=\radius];
  \filldraw[color=RoyalAzure]
    foreach \s in {0,...,\numexpr\n-1\relax} {
      (360/\n*\s:\radius) circle[radius=1.7pt]
      node[color=black, anchor=360/\n*\s] {$g^{\s}$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Note: I converted `circle(\radius)` and `circle(1.7pt)` to the new syntax `circle[radius=〈radius〉]`, because the old syntax `circle (〈radius〉)` is deprecated and may cause problems (at least with `pgfplots`, see [Drawing circles within an axis of pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525870/drawing-circles-within-an-axis-of-pgfplots) for instance).

Comment: I converted the examples to use the new syntax for the `circle` operation, namely `circle[radius=〈radius〉]`. You should reflect this change in your code in order to avoid problems in the future.