# A mistake in TikZ manual page 1002/1318: radius must be in place of diameter

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

In TikZ manual page 1002/1318, there is an example to create a circular array like this:

[image]

The problem is the author called the radius of each circle as the diameter.
Below is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
Let's draw circles at interesting points:
\foreach \x / \y / \diameter in {0 / 0 / 2mm, 1 / 1 / 3mm, 2 / 0 / 1mm}
\draw (\x,\y) circle (\diameter);
% Same effect
\foreach \center/\diameter in {{(0,0)/2mm}, {(1,1)/3mm}, {(2,0)/1mm}}
 \draw[yshift=2.5cm] \center circle (\diameter);;
\draw[red] [|-|] (0,0) -- ++(0,2mm);% I added this to measure the radius
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Am I right?

Comment: +1 That's right, report it in the bug tracker here [pgf-issues](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues)

Comment: The question is a bug report and should be addressed elsewhere

Comment: Rather than being a bug report I'd say that the OP is asking for clarification that this is indeed a bug, which seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: Moreover, for what I know (see manual 14.6 The Circle and Ellipse Operations, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525870/drawing-circles-within-an-axis-of-pgfplots) the syntax `circle(radius)` is deprecated, you should use `circle[radius=...]`. I imagine the manual is being updated, but it is so big that it's not easy to percolate changes

Comment: I've added a commit which replaces `\diameter` with `\r`, to pull request https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/pull/905. The old syntax of `... circle (<radius>)` is not modified since it _is_ documented in last two paragraphs of doc of `circle` operator, sec. 14.6 of pgfmanual 3.1.5b. PS: you can click any occurrences of operator `circle` in code examples of pgfmanual to jump to sec. 14.6.